Securing Azure DevOps
I'm trying to understand the security design of Azure DevOps services.
We have a conditional access policy that only allow connections to Azure DevOps when a client is:

on a system with Windows OS
the system is hybrid joined to our Entra ID
authenticated via MFA

Now, this works perfectly fine when going via a browser, but there are other ways to have access to e.g. Azure Repos.

I can create a Personal Access Token when logged on to a system that meets the above requirements. Then I can use this token in a git command line just fine:
git clone https://<token_goes_here>@dev.azure.com/<my_organisation>/<my_project>/_git/<my_repo>
Use e.g. Gitkraken and obtain an authorization code on a system that meets above requirements. Then I can use this code to authenticate with OAuth token on an untrusted system.
Use VS code and when signing in to Azure, capture the login URL, paste it on a trusted system, capture the callback URL and paste that (with the access code in the URL) on the untrusted system

I know we can:

restrict the creation of PATs, but we cannot completely prohibit this
set IP restrictions
restrict access from third-parties with OAuth tokens (this works properly when e.g. testing with birdeatsbug, but with GitKraken (as mentioned above) this doesn't have any effect)

The goal is to allow our users to work only from trusted, secured (hard disk encrypted) systems, to prevent leakage of data to untrusted systems.
How do you guys do this (without a written policy)?

For a Microsoft Entra ID-backed organization, DevOps can perform Conditional Access policy(CAP) validation which configured on Microsoft Entra ID.
However, DevOps only enforces conditional access policies when a user signs into services with their AAD credentials. Accessing DevOps using personal access tokens (PATs), alternate authentication, OAuth, and SSH keys circumvents conditional access policies. Please check the similar ticket here for your reference.
For Gitkraken, it used the Oauth App which target on the user profile for authentication. It applied to all devops organizations which owned by the user. Restricting access from third-parties with OAuth tokens from one devops organziation won't prevent the connection. Similar for VsCode connection.

Hope it helps!

Thank you. I expected this answer, but wanted to know other people's thoughts on this as well.
